# When was MFD renamed to FD8?

Tags: algorithm, flow

According to my understanding, the Multiple Flow Direction (MFD) algorithm was originally defined in *The Prediction of Hillslope Flow Paths for Distributed Hydrological Modelling using Digital Terrain Models* by Quinn et al. 1991. Since then it seems to have been renamed to FD8 to prevent confusion and I believe some may even refer to it as MD8 but I have failed to discover when this happened. This originally caused some confusion on a project I am working on.

I am looking for a reference or an explanation for when MFD became known as FD8 and if MD8 is also a valid name for the algorithm or am I mixing algorithms altogether?

Answer (score 2):

In Wilson et al. 2008 (http://spatial.usc.edu/wp-content/uploads/Water-in-the-Landscape.pdf)

"The FD8 multiple flow direction (MFD) algorithm developed by Quinn
et al. (1991) directs water to every adjacent downslope cell on a slope-
weighted basis."  p. 217.

Comment: That's from 2008. Terrain Analysis: Principles and Applications edited by Wilson & Gallant and released on 15 January 2000, also uses FD8 instead of MFD.